# How do I round -13422.8450 to -13422.84 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, numbers, rounding

I want to round off `-13422.8450` as `-13422.84` in SQL Server.

But using `ROUND(-13422.8450, 2)` is returning `-13422.85`

This is the full query:

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(-1 * 50 * 26845.69 / 100 AS NUMERIC(13, 4)), 2)
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a third parameter having non-zero value to [`ROUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function; the function will truncate instead of rounding:

```
SELECT ROUND(-13422.8450, 2)
-- -13422.8500

SELECT ROUND(-13422.8450, 2, 1)
-- -13422.8400
```

Be advised that casting from numeric to numeric will **round** the result before the round function is called. In your example you need to round (truncate), *then* cast.